# Select records that are not already joined and are unique basing on some columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I really find hard to express my problem in title clearly in one sentence. But here's the explanation and sample data:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tfamoNxujZhfTzxPPzefLt/2

```
create table customer_promotions (
customer_id integer, 
promotion_id integer);

create table promotions (
  promotion_id integer,
  type text,
  product_type text,
  percentage integer);

  insert into customer_promotions values 
  (1,1), 
  (1,5), 
  (2,3),
  (2,4),
  (3,6),
  (4,2);
  insert into promotions values 
  (1,'fixed_value', 'food',5),
   (2,'fixed_value', 'food',10),
    (3,'percentage', 'food',10),
     (4,'percentage', 'clothes',10),
      (5,'fixed_value', 'electronics',20),
       (6,'percentage', 'electronics',10),
        (7,'fixed_value', 'toys',15);
```

I want to find all promotions for particular customer (let's say `customer_id = 1`), that are not yet in use (present in table customer_promotions) AND do not share same `type` and `product_type` that is already in use.

So for customer 1 result should be:
promotion_id
3
4
6
7
I believe there's some simple solution using left join but I have like blackhole in mind right now.
Would be really grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one more join to find the attributes for the promotions that are already in use for a specific customer.

```
select unused.promotion_id, unused.type 
from promotions unused 
left join 
(  
   select promotions.promotion_id, promotions.type, promotions.product_type 
   from promotions inner join customer_promotions 
                   on customer_promotions.promotion_id = promotions.promotion_id
   where customer_id = 1
) used 
         on unused.type = used.type 
            and unused.product_type = used.product_type
where used.promotion_id is null
```

Comment: Thank you, really helpful. I find another challenge, let's add to this schema table customers, with just customer_id column, now how to find all customers to which given promotion can be added (and of course is not already added)? Including same logic as before, that promotion_type and type have to be unique?

Comment: Glad I could help. Do take a look at the other answer you were given and my comment under it. For your new question, I would create a subquery that joins the customer_promotions table with the promotions table, to find all customer_ids that already have a promotion with the same type and product_type as the given promotion. Then I would have my outer query select all id's from the customers table, that are NOT IN the subquery results. I assume of course that you know the type and product type of the promotion; if you only have its id, you need to fetch its details with another subquery or JOIN

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with:
Your fields   type and product_type make them varchar(100) instead of text.

```
   select * from promotions a 
   where not exists(select 1 from customer_promotions b 
   where a.promotion_id = b.promotion_id and b.customer_id = 1)
   and not exists
   (select 1 from promotions aa inner join 
   customer_promotions bb on aa.promotion_id = bb.promotion_id 
   where a.type = aa.type and a.product_type  = aa.product_type and bb.customer_id = 1)
```

Output:

```
promotion_id    type        product_type    percentage
3             percentage    food            10
4             percentage    clothes         10
6             percentage    electronics     10
7             fixed_value   toys            15
```

Comment: This works great and is probably cleaner than the left join solution. You just don't really need the first condition (first "not exists"), it is covered by the second one.